# Reduce spacing in table of contents (beamer)

Tags: beamer, spacing, table-of-contents

How can I reduce the spacing between the items of my table of contents in my `beamer` presentation? Here is my current LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\title[Short title]{My very long title that doesn't fit into the footer}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[currentsection, hideothersubsections]
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\clearpage

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[hideothersubsections]
\end{frame}


\section{Intro}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Welcome}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 1}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 2}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 2}
...
\end{frame}

\subsection{Red}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Red}
...
\end{frame}

\subsection{Green}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Green}
...
\end{frame}

\subsection{Blue}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Blue}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 3}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 3}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 4}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 4}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 5}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 5}
...
\end{frame}

\section{The end}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The end}
End of file :-)
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

See page 7, the point "The end" is missing and I need that one.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The internal command `\beamer@sectionintoc` (defined in the file `beamerbasetoc.sty`) controls how the section entries will be typeset in the ToC; it issues a `\vskip1.5em` that adds vertical spacing between section entries. With the help of the `etoolbox` package you can easily patch the command to add less vertical spacing. A little example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\beamer@sectionintoc}{\vskip1.5em}{\vskip0.5em}{}{}
\makeatother

\title[Short Title]{My very long title that doesn't fix into the footer}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[currentsection, hideothersubsections]
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\clearpage

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[hideothersubsections]
\end{frame}


\section{Intro}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Welcome}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 1}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 2}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 2}
...
\end{frame}

\subsection{Red}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Red}
...
\end{frame}

\subsection{Green}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Green}
...
\end{frame}

\subsection{Blue}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Blue}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 3}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 3}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 4}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 4}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 5}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 5}
...
\end{frame}

\section{The end}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The end}
End of file :-)
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works nice with the toc at the beginning of the presentation, but not with the toc such as it is shown between sections (with all section titles greyed out except for the current one). Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

For those like me who came looking for how to reduce the space in-between the final `subsection` of a `section` and the next `section` TOC entry as well as the OP's question, the answer by [@Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51458/273733) can be adapted as such:

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\beamer@sectionintoc}{\vskip1.5em}{\vskip0.5em}{}{}
\patchcmd{\beamer@sectionintoc}{\vfill}{\vskip0.2em}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Where the `\vfill` commands redefinition to `\vskip` can be modified to whatever value you desire. Before (without redefining either `\patchcmd`):

[image]

after adding the aforementioned `\patchcmd` commands (the MWE from the OP disallows `hideothersubsections` which for my purposes was not necessary):

[image]

I hope this is useful to others who reached the same point as me unsure as to what to do!

Modified code:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {options: -halt-on-error}
% arara: pdflatex: {options: -halt-on-error}

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\title[Short title]{My very long title that doesn't fit into the footer}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
}


\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\beamer@sectionintoc}{\vskip1.5em}{\vskip0.5em}{}{}
\patchcmd{\beamer@sectionintoc}{\vfill}{\vskip0.2em}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\clearpage

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}


\section{Intro}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Welcome}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 1}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 2}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 2}
...
\end{frame}

\subsection{Red}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Red}
...
\end{frame}

\subsection{Green}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Green}
...
\end{frame}

\subsection{Blue}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Blue}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 3}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 3}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 4}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 4}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 5}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 5}
...
\end{frame}

\section{The end}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The end}
End of file :-)
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```